# Samsung Edge Panel, кто-нибудь с ним работал?

Tags: java, android, samsung

Добрый день!

Кто-нибудь знает как создавать Edge Panel для Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge в Android Studio?

Буду благодарен любой информации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/edge